# Alternative to ltree in postgres with space support?

Tags: postgresql, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a inventory table that could have a category in a tree fashion, like:

Computers->PC
Computers->Tablets->Apple
Electronics->Computers->Others

For that, the ltree module look like the best fit. However, it can't accept spaces in the names, like "Personal Computers.Apple".

This is for input for end-users, so force them to make everything space-less is not ideal.

I tough in use normal LIKE 'Personal Computers*' but wonder if exist a alternative to this...

I will build a hierarchy based in the info of that field. I don't want to build another table to describe the hierarchy, because in my system the category field is almost flat, the deep is small and I think is more user-friendly.

Comment: Do end users really enter the data directly into the database? You could replace spaces with '_' in your application logic or in a before insert trigger.

Comment: I fail to see the problem. If you cannot accept space in character fields, there is something wrong, imho. Normally, you would do the child->parent connection on a numerical basis; the strings are functionally dependant on this numerical id (or a candidate key). The UI should handle the spaces, maybe present a dropdown list, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use integer or text arrays, ordered to represent the hierarchical structure of your data. I normally manage the array field via table triggers.

Something like `parent_node INTEGER, node_tree INTEGER[]` in your table schema should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column for uuid if possible and use that as the label. Use `replace( uuid_generate_v4()::text, '-', '_')` as default value for that column to make it suitable to be ltree label.